# Correlation - high r value but not significant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, p-value

I run Pearson correlation for 2 variables and results says that r = .46 which as I know means that strong positive relationship but p value is non significant p = .12

What this result means? Since my knowledge based on googling any help would be great!

Comment: How many observations do you have?

Comment: $r=0.42$ is a moderate (or weak-moderate), positive relationship. $r$ doesn't actually tell you anything about significance on its own

Comment: @Dave I have 12 observations

Comment: With only $12$ observations, you will need very compelling evidence of correlation (so a high observed correlation) to get a small p-value. Apparently your observed correlation is not high enough.

Answer (score 3):

It means that the effect is not strong enough, given your sample size, to determine it to be statistically different from zero.

With small data, you are going to need a very large effect to achieve significance.

Comment: Yes I think the problem is my small sample size which is 12. Thank you for your response helped a lot